# Is there a way to get the version from META6.json in Raku module code?

Tags: raku

I want to do something like this:

```
die "Fatal error: application version $MY-APPLICATION-VERSION"
```

Since a Raku module cannot assume the relative locations of files it was packaged with (for instance installed modules are all put into a flat directory structure) I can't just do `$?FILE.IO.add("../META6.json").slurp`. Is there a way to get the version declared in META6.json in a Raku app/module that may or may not be installed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of rakudo `v2019.03` modules may access the [Distribution](https://docs.raku.org/type/Distribution) object used to load it via [$?DISTRIBUTION](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables.html#$%3FDISTRIBUTION). This allows the following:

```
unit module My::Module;

BEGIN my $VERSION = $?DISTRIBUTION.meta<version>;
use My::SubModule:ver($VERSION); # ensure we only ever use the version included in this distribution

die "Fatal error: application version $VERSION"
```